# Why is function setOutlineThickness() slowing the program?

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a grid where I'm using one sf:RectangleShape object and with changing parameters of it inside a loop I can populate a wide area with them.   Now I want to make grid visible to assist with placing Rectangles.

But here comes the issue.

If I will use `rectPtr->getRect()->setOutlineThickness(-0.5f);` Note: Its pointer created from custome class. From unknown reasons final program becomes really slow and unstable. Its running just fine with `setOutlineThickness(0.f);`.  Im using negative value because of that grid, but there is no problem,. it do same with positive values.

Is there some way to use `setOutlineThickness();` function without slowing the program?

May it be some kind of bug?

I'm using `sf::Transform` 3x3 matrix at `window.draw()`, could be there some violation?

average FPS with setOutlineThickness(-1.f) = 16.fps

average FPS with setOutlineThickness(0.f) = 60.fps

many thanks

Comment: Try using an integer value (1.f instead of 0.5f). My guess is that using such a small value causes some extra computation (you can't draw half a pixel, so you graphics card has to figure out a way to render it).

Comment: I tryed. It have no problem with 0.5f. Doesnt matter what is plased inside. 1, 1.f,. -1.f ,0.5f. If there is something other than 0, it is somehow slowing final app.

Comment: Well, the fact that it slows down the app is inevitable. I don't know exactly how outlines work with SFML but I guess that it requires the drawing of 4 additional rectangles (16 vertices).

Comment: If you want a grid, maybe your best option is to draw only the lines using vertices

Comment: I guess it will be the best option. You got right that It could create 4 adittional rectangles. But Its weired. That object with outlines is just one rectangle shape on the heap that is drawn multiple times with diferrent positions,. 4000 times drawn one object. So by base logic,. there should be only +4 rectangle shapes set by outline at total.

Comment: I was looking for some documemtation where I could see inside default sfml functions, but unsucces. Is there some soure where i can find it? Dont know if sfml is oppen source or not.

Comment: I dont understand to it at all. In debug I see the program use 102 mb of memory total and it runs at 15FPS without set any framerate limit.. and my other project do the same,.. Im working on lighting and it takes 82mb of memory and run on 10.fps. average. My pc have 16gb RAM.. and I know that 32bit projects should use up to 2gb of it..